# Quadratic variation of the absolute value of the Brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Let $W=\{W_t: t \geq 0\} $ be the standard Brownian motion.

The quadratic variation for a stochastic process $X=\{X_t: t \geq 0\}$ is defined has
$$[X,X]_t=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}})^2=\int_0^t(dX_s)^2$$
where $t_i=\frac{ti}{n}$ and the limit is in $L^2$ sense.

**How can I compute $[|W|,|W|]_t$ , i.e. the quadratic variation of $|W_t|$?**

(I've tried using [Tanaka's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanaka%27s_formula) but I think the exercise wanted me to do it differently)

Comment: Do you know Tanaka's formula?

Comment: Never hear of it. But now there I see it, it seems it could be usefull